# Azure RHEL 8 VM - Apache 2.4 Package Availabilty

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, httpd, repository, packages

I've got a **RHEL 8.8** instance in **Azure**. This instance will replace our current **RHEL 7.9** instance running **Apache 2.4.34**. The RHEL 7.9 instance has the following httpd package installed: **httpd24-httpd**. The following apache packages are also available for install - **httpd** and **httpd24**.

On my RHEL 8 instance if I do a yum search or yum info on httpd the **httpd** package (version 2.4.37) is returned. If I do a **yum info** on the other httpd packages mentioned above nothing is returned, it can't find them. So that leads me to my question: Is **httpd24-httpd** and **httpd24** not available on RHEL 8 servers?

I'd like to get a solid answer before I install what's currently available by default in my repo. Red Hat mentions **Red Hat Software Collections (RHSCL)** and **Red Hat Update Infrastructure (RHUI)** repo's but everything seems to be **RHEL 7** focused.

Any help/advice clearing this up is appreciated, thanks!